# Divi Theme Integration jQuery Accordion External Links

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to link my footer faq questions to specific accordion panels on another page. So basically I just want my footer faq links to open the question it is tied to on the faq page.

HTML (footer links):

```
<div class="footer-faq">
<a id="faq-link-1" href="http://accesshealth.lunabyte.io/faqs/#my 
accordion">What is Access 
Health?</a><br />
<a id="faq-link-2" href="http://accesshealth.lunabyte.io/faqs/#my-
accordion">Who are the Access Health clinicians?</a><br />
<a id="faq-link-3"  
onclick="thing2();"href="http://accesshealth.lunabyte.io/faqs/#my-
accordion"> Does it matter where my insurance cover is?</a><br />
<a id="faq-link-4" onclick="thing3();" 
href="http://accesshealth.lunabyte.io/faqs/#my-accordion"> Who can be 
treated at Access Health?</a><br />
<a id="faq-link-5" onclick="thing4();" 
href="http://accesshealth.lunabyte.io/faqs/#my-accordion"> Which conditions 
are treated at Access Health?</a><br />
<a id="faq-link-6" onclick="thing5();" 
href="http://accesshealth.lunabyte.io/faqs/#my-accordion"> What preventative 
services are provided?</a><br />
<a id="view-all" href="http://accesshealth.lunabyte.io/faqs/">View All</a>
</div>
```

So when I click on any of these links it only opens the second panel in the accordion. So it is working to a degree but each link only opens the second panel.

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script>

jQuery(function thing($){
$(window).load(function(){
if(window.location.hash) {
$( '.et_pb_accordion_item_0 .et_pb_toggle_title').click();
}
});
});

jQuery(function thing1($){
$(window).load(function(){
if(window.location.hash) {
$( '.et_pb_accordion_item_1 .et_pb_toggle_title').click();
}
});
});

jQuery(function thing2($){
$(window).load(function(){
var et_hash = window.location.hash;
if(window.location.hash) {
$( '.et_pb_accordion_item_2 .et_pb_toggle_title').click();
}
});
});

jQuery(function thing3($){
$(window).load(function(){
var et_hash = window.location.hash;
if(window.location.hash) {
$( '.et_pb_accordion_item_3 .et_pb_toggle_title').click();
} 
});
});

jQuery(function thing4($){
$(window).load(function(){
var et_hash = window.location.hash;
if(window.location.hash) {
$( '.et_pb_accordion_item_4 .et_pb_toggle_title').click();
}
});
});

jQuery(function thing5($){
$(window).load(function(){
var et_hash = window.location.hash;
if(window.location.hash) {
$( '.et_pb_accordion_item_5 .et_pb_toggle_title').click();
}
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used below solution for all function

`$('.et_pb_accordion_item_4').children('.et_pb_toggle_title').click();`

Please check this solution.

Comment: Still, does the same thing.